# In php, is there any method to determine whether the incoming http request is POST or GET?

Tags: php, http, post, get

As title.

Also, I just use file_get_contents(php://input) to get them.
Also, I am just confused about how to use $_POST and $_GET in php, even after long time of learning in web!

As I know, they are array, but in many examples, I see people put in the key like

```
$_POST['key']
```

But what defines the key and its corresponding value? 
Now I am not getting html form from client, but the examples in internet mainly deal with that.

Hope someone can get my questions, and show some examples and solution to me , thanks!

Comment: As a side note; look into $_REQUEST, it's very useful if you need some code to be common for GET and POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, which when run in SAPI mode will ALWAYS contain the method of the HTTP request: GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD, etc.... Using this $_SERVER var is 100% reliable. Checking for the presence/absence of form fields is unreliable, especially if you're modifying the form - one typo on either side and your code fails because what's being looked for doesn't exist anymore.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHDO'] == 'POST') {
   $val = $_POST['somefield'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] will give you the type, but the key is usually defined by the variables provided int he previous page or URL content.

http://www.blah.com?key=something&key2=somethingelse

or a form on a page, etc.

the methods "post" hide the variables from a form and pass it silently instead of in the url as seen in the example above. GET will display them in the URL (if i remember correctly)